# War file hasn't auto deployed inside the JBoss Server

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

JBoss Server Used: jboss-eap-7.1.0

Used IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3

Can build the war file in target project folder but that created WAR 
hasn't deployed in JBOSS deployment path location which is "\jboss-eap-7.1.0\standalone\deployments"

JBOSS web.xml file can see in below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
  <context-root>/usermanagement</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: How are you deploying the application?

Comment: I have tried to deploy by using IDE called IntelliJ idea 13.1.3.

Comment: I'm not sure how Intellij deploys the application. You might want to look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deploying-a-web-app-into-wildfly-container.html

Comment: How are you trying to deploy it in exploded format/war format?Have you tried deploying it manually,without using Intellij does that work?As in by directly placing war in standalone/deployments

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: I have tried to deploy it manually and it has worked fine. The only thing wouldn't able to do via intellij idea.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is using the JBoss management API for doing the deployment. You won't see anything within the `standalone/deplyoments` directory.

To check your deployment state, look into the `server.log` file.